# saving top output using python

Tags: python

I have been playing with Python for almost five days and I honestly enjoy it.
I have this challenge and I couldn't solve it.
The challenge is to repeat the output of top command every 10 seconds and save it into a file.
Here is what I have done so far.

```
import time, os, threading

def repeat():
    print(time.ctime())
    threading.Timer(10, repeat).start()
    f = open('ss.txt', 'w')
    top = os.system("sudo top -p 2948")
    s = str(top)
    text = f.write(s)
    print(text)

repeat()
```

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: Have you found any way to get top output instead of calling command?? I mean using any system libs or python libs???

Answer (score 6):

The main problem here is that a call to `top` does not terminate immediately but runs continuously in a loops to display new data. You can change this behaviour by specifying the `-n1` option (`-n` allows you to specify the number of iterations).

Try something like this:

```
import subprocess

## use the following where appropriate within your loop
with open("ss.txt", "w") as outfile:
  subprocess.call("top -n1 -p 2948", shell=True, stdout=outfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to use `subprocess` for invoking another process. You need to pass the `file object` of the file where you want to write output. 
e.g.

```
    import time, os, threading, subprocess
    def repeat():
      print(time.ctime())
      threading.Timer(10, repeat).start()
      with open('ss.txt', 'w') as f:
          subprocess.call(["sudo","top","-p","2948"],stdout=f)
```

This should save the output of command to a file which you can read later.

Comment: I tried this on my system and output is being written to file pefectly. What error do you see?

Comment: subprocess.call("sudo top -n1 -p 2948", shell=True, stdout=f) by specifying the -n1 option (-n allows you to specify the number of iterations). thanks man for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `time.sleep()` function, and wait for 10 seconds before continuing.
Not sure whether this is what you want...

```
import time,os

def repeat(seconds,filename):
    while True:
        print(time.ctime())
        f = open(filename, 'w')
        top = os.system("sudo top -p 2948")
        s = str(top)
        time.sleep(seconds)
        f.write(s)

repeat(5,'ss.txt')
```

**Also**

1. `f.write` returns `None`, as it writes on the file, not returning
   any value, so it is useless storing that value.
2. check out [PEP 324](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/), it notes the features of `subprocess` module. (thx to @ajm)
3. `subprocess.Popen()` has a lot of functionality(tools), so it can replace many other 'tools', (see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module)) so you may consider that too.

Answer (score -1):

First, your code is not formated properly, it should look more like that:

```
import time, os, threading

def repeat():
  print(time.ctime())
  threading.Timer(10, repeat).start()
  f= open('ss.txt', 'w')
  top= os.system("sudo top -p 2948")
  s=str(top)
  text = f.write(s)
  print text

repeat()
```

Then, you might want to look into subprocess module - its the more modern and kosher way to call external commands than os.system. However, if your code works, what's the actual problem?

Comment: the problem is  i can't save it into a file.

Comment: Ok, in such case can you clarify your initial post with details on what the issue is, what errors are you getting and so on?